# Maximum value in array mips

Tags: arrays, mips

I'm trying to find the maximum value in a array and print out that value in the end.

```
.globl start
.data
array:  .word   8,2,31,81,12,10
size:   .word   6
max:    .word 0
.text
main:
jal start
start:
lw $t3, size #size
la $t1, array # get array address
lw $s5, ($t1)       # set max, $s5 to array[0]
add $t1, $t1, 4    # skip array[0]
add $t3, $t3, -1       # len = len - 1 
loop:

lw $t4, ($t1) # get n of array[n]

ble $t4,$s5,L1 #if t4 is not less than t5 we got a new max otherwise not.
lw $s5, 0($t4) #get element in array  <-- Pretty sure im doing something wrong here.
#sw $s5,0($t1) #max


L1:
add $t3, $t3, -1             #counter-1
addi $t1, $t1, 4 # advance array pointer
bnez $t3, loop #if not 0 then go on and loop

sw $s5, max #printing the max val of the array
lw $a0, max
li $v0, 1
syscall  
li $v0, 10
```

If I change the lw instruction to move the s5 var just changes value everytime t4 changes value. My problem is that s5 just changes everytime t4 changes. With the move instruction instead of lw the max value is 10, the last element of the array.

To clarify: I want the s5 variable to keep the value it has and ONLY change when i've found a new max value. At the moment it changes everytime t4 changes when I use the move instruction.

Sorry if the code looks horrible, new to MIPS so I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: Instead of `lw $s5,0($t4)` you should have `mov $s5,$t4`.

Comment: The problem with that is that s5 gets every value that t4 gets, it gives max the value 10 at the end.

Comment: The `lw` is in the delay slot of the `ble`, and thus it gets executed even if the branch is taken. Add a `nop` after the `ble` to move the `lw` out of the delay slot.

Comment: Wow it worked, thanks a lot markgz! I'm going to read more about nop and the delay slot. I did not know about that.